# Customize link style in leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, javascript-objects

I'm trying to customize the style of a link that will appear in a leaflet popup.

For some reason, I'm able to style the text-decoration of the link, and the font, but when I try to change the color of the text, nothing happens. I've tried in pretty much every way I can think of, including inline CSS where I added `style='color:#000;'` into the a tag. I've also included a `reset.css` file in the HTML document and this hasn't changed anything either.

The link is being pulled in from a separate Javascript document and then formatted in the popup with a `for` function.
Here is the code:

CSS:

```
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper .leaflet-popup-content {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
color: #000;

}

.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper a
.leaflet-popup-content a {
color: #000;
}

.leaflet-popup-tip-container {
text-align: center;
color: #000;
}

.direction {
color: #000;
  }

a {
color: inherit;
  }
```

JS:

```
var variable = [{
"directions": "<a href='link' target='_blanck' class='direction'>Get Directions</a>",
}]
```

Comment: have you tried !important ?

Comment: Yeah in leaflet you need to add !important to some of the css properties to make it work.

Comment: @ShadowFoOrm That worked! thank you! I'd heard you're not supposed to use that if you can avoid it so I figured I'd see if it's avoidable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use !important;

> I'd heard you're not supposed to use that if you can avoid it so I
>   figured I'd see if it's avoidable.

It's true, avoiding !important is really good.
But you have to know how css override rule works.

CSS < Inline style < Javascript styles < !important;
In your case you said you are getting the color with javascript.